# JSON.parse Dynamodb

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-dynamodb

Folks,
  Im getting back the following JSON object, which I would like to parse:

```
{"Count":1,"Items":[{"foo":{"S":"bar"}}]}
```

If I do the following, I get the 'bar' of the foo item?:

```
foo = JSON.stringify(result.Items)
foo = JSON.parse(foo)
console.log(foo)

fails if i try:
console.log(foo.bar)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there's no "bar" property of `result.Items` — it's an array.

Try

```
console.log(foo[0].foo.bar);
```

Or else, when you stringify it in the first place:

```
var foo = JSON.stringify(result.Items[0].foo);
```

and then

```
console.log(foo.bar);
```

should work.

Answer (score 6):

In your example you would actually need:

```
console.log(foo[0].foo.S); // "bar"
```

But I would suggest using **[dynamodb-marshaler](https://github.com/CascadeEnergy/dynamoDb-marshaler)**

A. Because I wrote it.

B. Because it translates DynamoDb attribute values for you so you don't need to deal with "S" type keys.

```
var item = unmarshalItem(result.Items[0]);
console.log(item.foo); // "bar"
```

or even more slick when you have multiple items returned:

```
var items = result.Items.map(unmarshalItem);
items.each(function(item) { console.log(item.foo); }); // "bar"
```

EDIT:

There is now a [DocumentClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) which does this marshal work as part of the aws-sdk-js